# Uncountable union of separable spaces is separable?

Tags: general-topology, functional-analysis, hilbert-spaces

If $V(x)$ is a separable Hilbert space, is $\bigcup_{x \in X}V(x)\times\{x\}$ separable when $X$ is an uncountable set? How to make it separable if it's not? What assumptions do I need?

Comment: What is the answer if $V(x)=\{0\}$ for all $x$?

Comment: So you want the final union to bbe just a topological space or something like the space of vector-valued funcitons? What is the relationship between the topology you want and topologies of $V(x)$?

Comment: @Norbert I want it to be like vector-valued functions. I am not really firm on topologies.. basically I want a function space in which I can define functions $f$ such that $f(x)$ is in $V(x)$ for $x \in X$.

Comment: @JonasMeyer I guess yes, but for non-trivial case I don't know

Comment: @soup: Why is it yes?  Based on your comment to Norbert it seems like there is not yet a precise question here, so I likely missed the point.  If you were taking the disjoint union, you would get an uncountable discrete space, which is not separable.

Comment: @JonasMeyer All I want to know is if the product space I wrote has a countable dense basis. Let us suppose that $V(x_0)$ has a countable dense basis $\{b_j\}$, and $V(x)$ has a basis given by $T(b_j,x)$ where $T$ is some nice map.

Comment: I changed $\cup_{x\in X}V(x)\times\{x\}$ to $\bigcup_{x\in X}V(x)\times\{x\}$.  I take that to be standard when you have subscripts or superscripts on $\bigcup$, and use $\cup$ only for things like $A\cup B$ and $A\cup\cdots\cup B$, etc.

Comment: If the intended topology on $\bigcup_{x\in X}(V(x)\times\{x\})$ is the usual "disjoint union" topology, then this space will not be separable, because the pieces $V(x)\times\{x\}$ are uncountably many disjoint, nonempty, open sets.   If, instead, we get to choose the topology on $\bigcup_{x\in X}(V(x)\times\{x\})$, then I'll choose the indiscrete topology, which makes it separable.  If the choice of topology on $\bigcup_{x\in X}(V(x)\times\{x\})$ is neither completely arbitrary nor required to be the usual topology, then soup should tell us what exactly is required.

Answer (score 2):

If you are referring to the product space together with the product topology then I am afraid it is not true. Take for instance the space $[0,1]^{[0,1]}$, which means uncounably many copies of $[0,1]$. This space is not separable. Since this space is compact and Hausdorff being separable is actually equivalent to being metrizeable. For this reason I don't think there is a reasonable way to "make" this space separable, since I don't see a reasonable way to make it a metric space without changing the topology completely.

Comment: Suppose $X=[0,X_0]$ in my notation. What topology can I give it?

Comment: I might be missing something, because I don't see how this relates to the question exactly. There is a union of copies of Hilbert space in the question, not an infinite product of $[0,1]$.  (Separable compact Hausdorff spaces need not be metrizable.  E.g. $\beta \mathbb N$.)

Comment: Actually, Edward, your space is separable by the theorem Paul cites. Being separable and being metrizable are not equivalent in compact Hausdorff spaces. What would be equivalent in a CHS is being separable and metrizable and being second countable.

Answer (score 1):

There is a [result from Pondiczery, Hewitt and Marczewski](http://planetmath.org/HewittMarczewskiPondiczeryTheorem.html):

> If there are not more than $\mathfrak{c}$ ( which is the continuum), separable topological spaces, then their product is still separable.